# Difference between sick and ill

Tags: adjectives

What is difference between Ill and Sick, How do I say "sick people" or "ill people" to refer to people not feeling well?

Comment: **ill** used before a noun means _bad or harmful_ : the neglect and ill treatment of children.....unable to join the army because of ill health... an ill omen...harbor no ill intentions toward them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, I was not aware of the differences between both either; however, after searching for it for a while, I found out some interesting differences between both:

**Ill**:

- Is normally used to refer to long-term diseases, such as cancer,
  pneumonia and etc..
- Can never be used attributively (before the noun) - ex: *ill child*.
  Instead, it can only be used postpositively (after the noun) or
  predicatively (after a linking or copula verb) ex: *A child ill - He
  seems ill.*
- Ill also works as a *prefix* when implying something made in a bad manner: *The ill-painting of my house, we should have never employed that guy!*

**Sick**:

- Is an informal and short term, usually refers to short sickness such as one that unables you to go to school for one or two days.
- Can be used attributively, postpositively and predicatively, ex: *I saw a sick child; the child sick; the child seems sick.*

Comment: But interestingly, "ill" is sometimes used before a noun when it is used metaphorically. "It's an ill wind that blows no good." "Ill-gotten gains", etc.

Comment: Interesting, Jaw. You also reminded me of adding the fact that "ill" also works as a suffix when implying something made in a bad way. I will add it up on my answer.

Comment: I've never seen **unables** used like that. Even [Scrabble](https://www.anagrammer.com/scrabble/unables) does not allow it, yet the meaning is quite clear. Interesting.

Comment: @Davo - Cambridge cites such uses of the prefix **ill**:
 https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ill

Comment: @Davo Able and unable are not verbs. Conjugating unable as if it were a transitive verb is kind of fun and interesting, but of course, the standard word to use there would be "disables." And then you'd use "from" as the preposition.

Answer (score 2):

*Sick* and *ill* are both adjectives that mean ‘not in good health’. We use both *sick* and *ill* after a verb such as *be, become, feel, look* or *seem*:

> I was ill for a time last year, but I’m fine now.
>
> Nancy looks ill. I wonder what’s wrong with her.
>
> I felt sick and had to go home at lunchtime.

We can use *sick* before a noun but we don’t normally use *ill* before a noun:

> She’s been looking after a sick child this week, so she’s not at work.
>
> **Not**: … an ill child …

In American English *sick* means more generally ‘to be unwell’.